# How can I tell Tomcat to use UTF-8 internally?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

So I have this very simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="formpost.do" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="id">Your name please:</label>
    <input id="id" type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<%= request.getAttribute("name") %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type "ğğğ" in the form, I see "ğğğ" as expected in output.jsp. The Servlet that handles this form looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

    httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String name = httpServletRequest.getParameter("name");
    httpServletRequest.setAttribute("name",name);

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/text.txt"));
    printWriter.write(name);
    printWriter.flush();
    printWriter.close();

    httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp")
            .forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

The problem is, in text.txt file I will see "???" instead of "ğğğ". I have been trying to solve this for hours but no luck..

I have

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

in Windows environmental variables, but it changes nothing as far as I can say.

When I debug this application, the variable "name" is seen as "ğğğ" in the debugger window if it helps at all.

So how can I make the System.out print the correct characters?

**EDIT 1**
When I create a separate Java project and simply run:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/text.txt"));
    printWriter.write("ğğğ");
    printWriter.flush();
    printWriter.close();
}
```

everything is as expected in the text file.

**EDIT 2**
I already have in my server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: What do you use to "see txt.file" - It it possible you don't read that file as UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a Tomcat issue. It's a Java issue with how you are writing to the file.

Use the appropriate character set when writing.

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/text.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

and reading, obviously.

Comment: Why do not I need this when I simply compile and run a java class with only one main method? Why is everything fine then? And how can I apply this to System.out.println()?

Comment: @KorayTugay It's possible the Java process which launches Tomcat, launches with a different default character set. As for `System.out`, I have to check but I think it uses the default as well.

Comment: @KorayTugay Yeah, the `System` class is initialized with a `PrintStream` that uses a character encoding retrieved from a system property named `sun.stdout.encoding`. These are properties initialized by the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. Can I make Tomcat start with utf-8 then? Because currently System.out.println also does not print correct characters and this is quite important.

Comment: @KorayTugay The `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` (**note the `-`**) VM argument should be enough. Instead of setting it in the Windows env properties, open up your `catalina.bat` or `startup.bat`, find where the `Java` command is being constructed, and add it there.

Comment: @KorayTugay See [here](http://davidbits.blogspot.ca/2010/12/how-to-change-tomcat-default-character.html) for example. But do it in the `.bat` file on Windows.

Comment: @KorayTugay I would not try and set `file.encoding` for [these reasons](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515). Always tell the encoder what encoding you want to save your character data as.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solves the "writing text" problem but not the System.out problem. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @McDowell Thanks. The real thing I want to solve is actually to properly write in System.out.println. The text file was mostly for testing and asking a question which I tought would get me to the solution as well.

Comment: @KorayTugay Consider using a full fledged logging library. Note that Tomcat redirects `System.out` to a its `catalina.out` file or whatever you configured.

Comment: There must be a way, isn't it?

Comment: @KorayTugay System.out uses lossy obsolete encodings on Windows; using System.out in an application server is generally considered a bug; use a proper logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 issues can be tricky. But in Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu I handle it this way.  First find the `server.xml` file & open it up for editing. I like to use `nano` but you should use whatever editor you feel comfortable with:

```
sudo nano /etc/tomcat6/server.xml
```

Now look for the fragment for `<Connector…` and place `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in there. In one of my setups it looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need in this case is to set the connector in server.xml like the following:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8/>
```

Of course in the connector you should set whatever other properties you need

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I made it work.

This is the JSP file I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="postform.do" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html");
    httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    final String name = httpServletRequest.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);
    final PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
    writer.print(name);
    writer.flush();
}
```